# Lag in counting tagged questions after re-tagging (may be just caching?)

Tags: discussion, bug, status-bydesign, tags

I just [manually re-tagged a couple of questions to merge 2 tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25944/so-possible-tag-merge-clustered-index-21-vs-clustered-indexing-3).

However, when confirming that the re-tagging worked:

- It took ~1-2 minutes for the list of questions for the "cleaned-out" tag to become empty.
- **More importantly, even after the list was empty, [it still says that there are 2 questions tagged with "clustered-indexing"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/clustered-indexing) despite there being none**.

I assume it's just some lag due to caching?

**UPDATE: Definitely caching, as the count now is down to correct zero**

Comment: When you first floated it, there were 3 tagged so, did one a while back, cache updated to show only 2 who knows when after that.

Comment: I just went through and re-tagged around 30 questions, and it's funny because certain tabs say there are 30 questions in that tag, but no questions show up, while other tabs say there are no questions at all for the tag. It's too bad SO can't use perfect caching, but it's understandable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The tag list is heavily cached so it may take a while for you to see any changes in the counts.